# Conditionally Rendered Primefaces autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a functional primefaces autocomplete that works just fine when it isn't conditionally rendered. This autocomplete code is directly from the Primefaces [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/primefaces-showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml), so I know its good. However, if I set a rendered attribute on the autocomplete that toggles based on whether or not an input element contains text, the autocomplete will render when the input element gets text as expected, but the autocomplete search and dropdown doesn't work.

There was a similar question asked years ago with no answer.
[primefaces autoComplete don't work with rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20542581/primefaces-autocomplete-dont-work-with-rendered)

I am on Primefaces 10 and
Jboss EAP 7.3.0.GA Wildfly Core 10.1.2 Final-redhat-00001 and
JSF version 3.0.0.SP01-redhat-00001 and
jboss-jsf-api_2.3_spec

```
<h:form xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"/>

<p:inputText value="#{autoCompleteView.input}" ><p:ajax event="blur" update="@form"/></p:inputText>

    <p:autoComplete id="pojo" value="#{autoCompleteView.country1}" 
rendered="#{not empty autoCompleteView.input}"
         completeMethod="#{autoCompleteView.completeCountry}"
           var="country" itemLabel="#{country.name}" itemValue="#{country}"
           converter="#{countryConverter}"  scrollHeight="250" dropdown="true"/>

</h:form>
```

```
package mil.mhs.tc2.poe.view.oe;

import org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class AutoCompleteView {

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    private String input;
    private String txt1;
    private String txt2;
    private String txt3;
    private String txt4;
    private String txt5;
    private String txt6;
    private String txt7;
    private String txt8;
    private String txt9;
    private String txt10;
    private Country country1;
    private Country country2;
    private Country country3;
    private Country country4;
    private Country country5;
    private List<Country> selectedCountries;

    @Inject
    private CountryService countryService;

    public List<String> completeText(String query) {
        String queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase();
        List<String> countryList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Country> countries = countryService.getCountries();
        for (Country country : countries) {
            countryList.add(country.getName());
        }

        return countryList.stream().filter(t -> t.toLowerCase().startsWith(queryLowerCase)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public List<String> noResults(String query) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    public List<Country> completeCountry(String query) {
        String queryLowerCase = query.toLowerCase();
        List<Country> countries = countryService.getCountries();
        return countries.stream().filter(t -> t.getName().toLowerCase().contains(queryLowerCase)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void onItemSelect(SelectEvent<String> event) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Country Selected", event.getObject()));
    }

    public void onEmptyMessageSelect() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Empty message selected"));
    }

    public String getTxt1() {
        return txt1;
    }

    public void setTxt1(String txt1) {
        this.txt1 = txt1;
    }

    public String getTxt2() {
        return txt2;
    }

    public void setTxt2(String txt2) {
        this.txt2 = txt2;
    }

    public String getTxt3() {
        return txt3;
    }

    public void setTxt3(String txt3) {
        this.txt3 = txt3;
    }

    public String getTxt4() {
        return txt4;
    }

    public void setTxt4(String txt4) {
        this.txt4 = txt4;
    }

    public String getTxt5() {
        return txt5;
    }

    public void setTxt5(String txt5) {
        this.txt5 = txt5;
    }

    public String getTxt6() {
        return txt6;
    }

    public void setTxt6(String txt6) {
        this.txt6 = txt6;
    }

    public String getTxt7() {
        return txt7;
    }

    public void setTxt7(String txt7) {
        this.txt7 = txt7;
    }

    public String getTxt8() {
        return txt8;
    }

    public void setTxt8(String txt8) {
        this.txt8 = txt8;
    }

    public String getTxt9() {
        return txt9;
    }

    public void setTxt9(String txt9) {
        this.txt9 = txt9;
    }

    public String getTxt10() {
        return txt10;
    }

    public void setTxt10(String txt10) {
        this.txt10 = txt10;
    }

    public Country getCountry1() {
        return country1;
    }

    public void setCountry1(Country country1) {
        this.country1 = country1;
    }

    public Country getCountry2() {
        return country2;
    }

    public void setCountry2(Country country2) {
        this.country2 = country2;
    }

    public Country getCountry3() {
        return country3;
    }

    public void setCountry3(Country country3) {
        this.country3 = country3;
    }

    public Country getCountry4() {
        return country4;
    }

    public void setCountry4(Country country4) {
        this.country4 = country4;
    }

    public Country getCountry5() {
        return country5;
    }

    public void setCountry5(Country country5) {
        this.country5 = country5;
    }

    public List<Country> getSelectedCountries() {
        return selectedCountries;
    }

    public void setSelectedCountries(List<Country> selectedCountries) {
        this.selectedCountries = selectedCountries;
    }

    public void setCountryService(CountryService countryService) {
        this.countryService = countryService;
    }

    public char getCountryGroup(Country country) {
        return country.getName().charAt(0);
    }
}
```

```
package mil.mhs.tc2.poe.view.oe;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@FacesConverter(value = "countryConverter", managed = true)
public class CountryConverter implements Converter<Country> {
    @Inject
    private CountryService countryService;
    @Override
    public Country getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value != null && value.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                return countryService.getCountriesAsMap().get(Integer.parseInt(value));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Conversion Error", "Not a valid country."));
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Country value) {
        if (value != null) {
            return String.valueOf(value.getId());
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
package mil.mhs.tc2.poe.view.oe;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Country implements Serializable, Comparable<Country> {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private Locale locale;
    private boolean rtl;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(int id, Locale locale) {
        this(id, locale.getDisplayCountry(), locale.getCountry().toLowerCase(), locale);
    }

    public Country(int id, Locale locale, boolean rtl) {
        this(id, locale.getDisplayCountry(), locale.getCountry().toLowerCase(), locale);
        this.rtl = rtl;
    }

    public Country(int id, String name, String code) {
        this(id, name, code, null);
    }

    public Country(int id, String name, String code, Locale locale) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Locale getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return locale == null ? "en" : locale.getLanguage();
    }

    public String getDisplayLanguage() {
        return locale == null ? "English" : locale.getDisplayLanguage();
    }

    public boolean isRtl() {
        return rtl;
    }

    public void setRtl(boolean rtl) {
        this.rtl = rtl;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Country country = (Country) o;
        return id == country.id
                && Objects.equals(name, country.name)
                && Objects.equals(code, country.code);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, code);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Country o) {
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }

}
```

```
package mil.mhs.tc2.poe.view.oe;


import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class CountryService {

    private List<Country> countries;
    private Map<Integer, Country> countriesAsMap;
    private List<Country> locales;
    private Map<Integer, Country> localesAsMap;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        countries = new ArrayList<>();
        locales = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] isoCodes = Locale.getISOCountries();

        for (int i = 0; i < isoCodes.length; i++) {
            Locale locale = new Locale("", isoCodes[i]);
            countries.add(new Country(i, locale));
        }

        Collections.sort(countries, (Country c1, Country c2) -> c1.getName().compareTo(c2.getName()));

        int i = 0;
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.US));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.FRANCE));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.GERMANY));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.ITALY));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.KOREA));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("es", "ES")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ca", "ES")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("nl", "NL")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pt", "BR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pt", "PT")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ar", "SA"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("cs", "CZ")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("el", "GR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("fa", "IR"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hi", "IN")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("in", "ID")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hr", "HR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("hu", "HU")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("iw", "IL"), true));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ka", "GE")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("lt", "LT")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("lv", "LV")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("no", "NO")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("pl", "PL")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ro", "RO")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("ru", "RU")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sk", "SK")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sl", "SI")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sr", "RS")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("sv", "SE")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("tr", "TR")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("uk", "UA")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, new Locale("vi", "VN")));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.SIMPLIFIED_CHINESE));
        locales.add(new Country(i++, Locale.TRADITIONAL_CHINESE));
    }

    public List<Country> getCountries() {
        return new ArrayList<>(countries);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Country> getCountriesAsMap() {
        if (countriesAsMap == null) {
            countriesAsMap = getCountries().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getId, country -> country));
        }
        return countriesAsMap;
    }

    public List<Country> getLocales() {
        return new ArrayList<>(locales);
    }

    public Map<Integer, Country> getLocalesAsMap() {
        if (localesAsMap == null) {
            localesAsMap = getLocales().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Country::getId, country -> country));
        }
        return localesAsMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your XHTML code doesn't look right to me the way you have your `h:form`.  You have invalid syntax for an XHTML page?

Answer (score 1):

Your scope is wrong for this case. Try to change it to @ViewScoped and import from:

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
```

And implements Serializable for not error, like this:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class AutoCompleteView implements Serializable{
```

And correct your h:form as Melloware said

Look at this primefaces code for more detail: [source](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/07224e824215fb39e824d5dc47fb91c6ab5980ea/primefaces-showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/showcase/view/input/AutoCompleteView.java)

Answer (score 0):

There could be a number of reasons why your Primefaces autocomplete component isn't working when you've conditional rendered it. Perhaps the most likely reason is that the ID of the component is not being correctly updated when the component is re-rendered.